# Problem with Django reverse()

Tags: django, reverse

I am missing something really basic here.

I am trying to reuse django's change password views. I have following in urls.py:

```
(r'^change-password/$', 'profile.views.change_password', {},'change_password'),
url(r'^change-password-done/$', 'profile.views.password_change_done', name='django.contrib.auth.views.password_change_done'),
```

and in corresponding views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_change, password_change_done

def change_password(request,template_name="password_change_form.html"):
    """Change Password"""
    return password_change(request,template_name=template_name)

def password_change_done(request, template_name="password_change_done.html"):
    return render_to_response(template_name,(),context_instance= RequestContext(request))
```

but I am getting following error:

> Reverse for
>   'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change_done'
>   with arguments '()' and keyword
>   arguments '{}' not found.

looked at the source and saw this line:

```
post_change_redirect = reverse('django.contrib.auth.views.password_change_done')
```

If I change my urls.py entry to following , I do not get the above error:

```
url(r'^change-password-done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change_done', name='anything'),
```

but I am confused as reverse() should look-up using the "name" parameter? What am I missing here?

I am using django 1.2.3

Answer (score 2):

Josh has the explanation, but you are doing this wrong. If you want to overrride the `post_save_redirect`, then pass that in as a parameter when you call the view:

```
def change_password(request,template_name="password_change_form.html"):
    return password_change(request, template_name=template_name, 
                           post_save_redirect=reverse('my_done_page'))
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_change).

Answer (score 1):

The `reverse` function doesn't just do lookups on name.

[Reverse Documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse).

> reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, current_app=None)
>     viewname is either the function name (either a function reference, or the string version of the name, if you used that form in urlpatterns) or the URL pattern name.

So, by doing `reverse('django.contrib.auth.views.password_change_done')`, it will look up that view name within the `urls.py` regexes, and fallback to looking for the `name` keyword argument if the viewname doesn't resolve.

Comment: That was exactly the part in the documentation that I could not understand. when I do `reverse('django.contrib.auth.views.password_change_done')`, it should fallback to looking for name keyword argument in the case when i have `url(r'^change-password-done/$', 'profile.views.password_change_done', name='django.contrib.auth.views.password_change_done'),
`